# ChromeDriver(Capabilities capabilities) is deprecated

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, desiredcapabilities

I use `ChromeDriver 2.33` with `WebDriver 3.6.0` and try to set default directory for file download.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", Vars.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT);
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

I found this in docs:

> Use ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions) instead. Creates a new ChromeDriver
>   instance. The capabilities will be passed to the chromedriver service.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Phoenix : Sorry, I asked for a workaround to solve this.

Comment: @plaidshirt I've added an answer with workaround for this. Please accept it if, it resolves your query.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I hope you wanted to ask about the workaround to avoid the deprecation.

The old method of just building with `Capabilities` is deprecated. Now, it takes a `ChromeDriverService` & `Capabilities` as parameters. So, just a build a `ChromeDriverService` and pass the same along with your `Capabilities` to remove the deprecation warning.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                    .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/chromedriver"))
                    .usingAnyFreePort()
                    .build();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, capabilities);
```

**EDIT:** 
Since `ChromeDriver(service, capabilities)` is deprecated now as well, you can use,

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/chromedriver"))
                            .usingAnyFreePort()
                            .build();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.merge(capabilities);    
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

However, You can completely skip `DesiredCapabilities` and use only `ChromeOptions` with `setCapability` method like,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("capability_name", "capability_value");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: It is working, but `ChromeDriver()` method is signed as deprecated in this case too.

Comment: @Sidhar: Thanks! Just a little fix: Variable `driver` should be `WebDriver` instead of `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: @plaidshirt you can assign it to `WebDriver` as `ChromeDriver` extends `RemoteWebDriver` and `RemoteWebDriver` implements `WebDriver`

Comment: @plaidshirt may I know why my answer was not accepted

Answer (score 3):

The new way to use chrome capabilities is like this :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    // proxy.setHttpProxy("myhttpproxy:3337");
    // options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
    // options.addArguments("--headless");
    // options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    // options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    // options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
    // options.addArguments("--lang=fr-CA");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can get more options by looking at this site : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities