# Has the Webdriver support to set proxy in the driver instance removed? Unable to set proxy in driver using desired capability

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, http-proxy, desiredcapabilities

I have the following code:

```
public class LoadBrowserAndSurf {
    @Test
    public void loadAndSurf() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Desktop\\Automation Requirements\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        String proxyString= "13.228.117.219";
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyString);
        DesiredCapabilities browserProxy =new DesiredCapabilities();
        browserProxy.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,proxy);
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(browserProxy);
        wd.get("http://www.globe.com.ph/");
    }
}
```

In eclipse oxygen this code is able to initiate the driver version, however it is not accessing the proxy.

When try I the same code in the IntelliJ editor, it strikes out the ChromeDriver in the driver object initiation line i.e:

```
WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(browserProxy);
```

And states message as:

> ChromeDriver(org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is depricated

Is there a way I can add this proxy in the driver instance when it launches in runtime?

Comment: The old method of just building with Capabilities is deprecated. Now, it takes a ChromeDriverService & Capabilities as parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786043/chromedrivercapabilities-capabilities-is-deprecated

Comment: Great thanks! I tried the following and it worked well.

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("capability_name", "capability_value");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);