# How to fix DesiredCapabilities in Selenium 4.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium4

I have a piece of code which sets browser name for the grid. However, DesiredCapabilities is deprecated in Selenium 4.0. How can I fix this code so that it works as the same in 4.0?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

if (prop.getBrowser().equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
capabilities.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.chrome().getBrowserName());
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786043/chromedrivercapabilities-capabilities-is-deprecated> might answer your question. Please, check if their solution works for you as well or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record *Selenium v4.x* is still in *alpha* stage and yet to be released for *General availability (GA)* for *Production* usage.

Snapshot:

[image: Selenium4x]

---

### Recommended Usage

The recommendation will be to continue using *Selenium v3.141.59* and keep your framework adjusted to the current implementation of [DesiredCapabilities](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) class till *Selenium v4.x* is GAed for *production* use successfully completing the *alpha* and *beta* cycles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using 3.141 at the moment but my question was about what to do when I have to migrate to the new version.

Comment: Need to wait for the final **jars**, associated **javadocs** and the **API Documentation** to be published to make the transition smoother.

Comment: I tried to switch to 4.0.0 because the docker images for chromedriver are using Selenium standalone 4.0.0-beta-1 so I thought it would be better to match the server version than to stick with the stable 3.141.59 client.